# Why my textures are moving on an animated mesh

Tags: animation, texturing

I'm recently working on a project. I'm using the ironman 3d model and I animated it with Mixamo.

After I added the Materials I found the scratches and smudges textures on the mesh were moving all over the Mesh whenever the mesh is animated.

I'm using the generated coordinates through a mapping node, however, the texture moves whenever the mesh is animated. I'm using blender 2.8 beta.

This is the link to my video.
https://youtu.be/b4eegh76wiw

Comment: Don't use generated coordinates. It is time for you to learn to use UV coordinates.

Comment: It does the same with UV coordinates. I used UV coordinates, same problem again the textures are moving. Please help.